# Run MONO application in a script on inittab (DEBIAN)

Tags: c#, mono, xterm

I'm trying to add a mono program in a script respawning in inittab.
I think the problem is DISPLAY, but I'm not sure.
In .xinitrc it's launched xterm. If I run my script here, it works, but I need it to run at startup,
some help?
Thank you so much.

Comment: It should help if you posted the actual script

Comment: This is the message: An exception was thrown by the type initialize for System.Window.Forms:XplatUI: Could not open display (X-server required. Check you DISPLAY environment variable) Thanks, I'm lost... Monica.

Comment: it's solved. I add my mono program in .xinitrc and it works!